# What am I parsing? Is this a Tuple?

Tags: json, swift

I have the following JSON data that I'm going to parse,

```
{ photos =
 { page = 1;
     photo = (
       {
         datetaken = "2016-03-20 12:30:05";
         title = Elurra;
         "url_h" = "https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1693/25298124964_4c44d0b1cf_h.jpg";
       },
       {
         datetaken = "2016-03-20 12:34:42";
         title = "Bianchi Rekord 745 campagnolo GS";
         "url_h" = "https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1505/25298125964_4469be38e1_h.jpg";
       }
     );
     total = 1000;
 };
 stat = ok;
}
```

[Challenge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7ztn.png)

the "photo" up there in JSON, is that a tuple? why does it have "()" brackets. I'm just trying to make sure I get that JSON data properly.

Comment: `{ }` is dictionary. `( )` is array.

Comment: that isn't valid json.

Comment: @DanielA.White No, it's the output of printing a dictionary from parsing JSON.

Comment: @rmaddy fair enough but the OP calls it json.

Comment: Why is it a valid JSON? Isn't it only with  arrays like "[ ]" or Objects with "{ }" I have never seen anything with "(  )"

Comment: It's not valid JSON. Is this the actual data, exactly as you've received it, or are you printing out something that isn't JSON (like a Dictionary?)

Comment: Yeah, its an online challenge that I'm working on. I will post up there

Answer (score 0):

> I have the following JSON data that I'm going to parse

No, you don't. You have misread the first sentence of the "challenge". It says that the JSON has *already* been parsed. What they are showing you is the printout of what it got parsed into, namely, an NSDictionary whose `"photos"` value is a nested NSDictionary. The `"photo"` value you're asking about is an NSArray of two NSDictionaries.